# Javascript error - Event Listener error on page load

Tags: javascript, html, events, addeventlistener

i am working on a weather app and i'm getting this error once the page loads
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" on line 36

here is the Code Snippet for the Html :

```
<div class="weather - app">
          <div class="panel">
            <form >
                <input type="text"
                       class="search"  
                       placeholder="Search Location .."/>
                <button type="submit"
                        class="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
            <ul class="cities">
                <li class="city">Paris</li>
                <li class="city">Las Vegas</li>
                <li class="city">Japan</li>
                <li class="city">Sfax</li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src = "main.js" ></script>`
```

.............................................................................

and for the main.js :

```
const app = document.querySelector('.weather-app');
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const search = document.querySelector('.search');
const btn = document.querySelector('.submit');
const cities = document.querySelectorAll('.city');
```

```
//add sumbit event to the form
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //if input field(search bar) empty throw an alert
    if (search.value.length == 0) {
        alert('Please type in a City name !');
    } else {
        //change default city name to the one written in search bar 
        cityInput = search.value;
        search.value = "";
        app.style.opacity = "0";
    }
});
```

Comment: add  class property to your form in html: <form class="form">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `querySelector` uses the CSS selectors to find an element in your page,
the selector you passed is `.form` which means *find an element with a class called form* and this does not appear in your HTML anywhere, so the correct selector is 'form' without a `.`
since `.` represents a class search

so the full code is

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
```

or you can add class to your form

```
<form class="form">
...
```

for more details about CSS selectors see this
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a .form class in your html

```
<div class="weather - app">
          <div class="panel">
            <form >
                <input type="text"
                       class="search"  
                       placeholder="Search Location .."/>
                <button type="submit"
                        class="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </form>
            <ul class="cities">
                <li class="city">Paris</li>
                <li class="city">Las Vegas</li>
                <li class="city">Japan</li>
                <li class="city">Sfax</li>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src = "main.js" ></script>
```

Remove the . if you want to query the DOM for a tag

```
const form = document.querySelector('.form');
```